# Why is one way of json to object working and the other throwing null error? Dart/Flutter null safety trouble

Tags: json, flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I'm learning how to use json, not used to Dart null safety & I don't like it so far. But I will have no choice but to adapt to it. I'm trying to parse my json object list into a list of objects. I was able to work out the basics in my main, but when I attempt to create an actual method in a class using the same structure I'm getting a null error. As far as I can tell I'm doing the exact same thing in both with addition of the loop for iterating the entire json list.

Note: I of course did try inserting the optional ? where it asks but the IDE will not allow this.

Can someone help with explaining what I'm doing wrong here?

***Error for class method jsonToDatabaseSyncItem()***

```
lib/services/remote_database_services.dart:52:43: Error: Property 'length' cannot be accessed on 'List<dynamic>?' because it is potentially null.
 - 'List' is from 'dart:core'.
Try accessing using ?. instead.
    final jsonListLength = jsonObjectList.length;
                                          ^^^^^^
lib/services/remote_database_services.dart:55:38: Error: Operator '[]' cannot be called on 'List<dynamic>?' because it is potentially null.
 - 'List' is from 'dart:core'.
      var jsonObject = jsonObjectList[index]['DatabaseSyncItem'];
```

***Class method (class- RemoteDatabaseService)***

```
// This method will get server database
  Future<List<dynamic>?> getRemoteDatabase() async {
    final events = QueryBuilder<ParseObject>(ParseObject('Event'));
    final apiResponse = await events.query();
    if (apiResponse.success && apiResponse.result != null) {
      return apiResponse.results;
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  }

// Method to parse json result list back to objects
  Future<List<dynamic>?> jsonToDatabaseSyncItem() async {
    final remoteDatabaseList = await getRemoteDatabase();
    final jsonObjectList = await Future.value(remoteDatabaseList);     /// This method throws the above
    final jsonListLength = jsonObjectList.length;                      /// error when run in main

    for (var index = 0; index == jsonListLength; index++) {
      var jsonObject = jsonObjectList[index]['DatabaseSyncItem'];
      print(jsonObject);
    }
  }
```

***Main file working code***

```
Future<void> main(List<String> arguments) async {

final test = remoteDatabaseServices.getRemoteDatabase();
  Future<List<dynamic>?> getList() {
    return Future.value(test);
  }

  var list = await getList();
  print(list?.length);
  var jsonObject = list![0]['DatabaseSyncItem'];
  print(jsonObject);

  var toObject = DatabaseSyncItem.fromJson(jsonObject);
  print(toObject);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem with null-safety seems to be a missing understanding about the feature. I will recommend you to read through the documentation here and read all the chapters: https://dart.dev/null-safety

About your code, you should consider when something can be `null` and when you can check the `null` and handle that case. In your example, it seems like `getRemoteDatabase()` should just return an empty `List` if an error happens or no result is returned. So we don't need to have the return type of this method as `Future<List<dynamic>?>` if we rewrite the method a bit:

```
Future<List<dynamic>> getRemoteDatabase() async {
  final events = QueryBuilder<ParseObject>(ParseObject('Event'));
  final apiResponse = await events.query();
  if (apiResponse.success) {
    return apiResponse.results ?? <dynamic>[];
  } else {
    return <dynamic>[];
  }
}
```

(the `??` operator will here test if `apiResponse.results` is null, if that is the case, we return `<dynamic>[]`. If not, we use the value of `apiResponse.results`).

Since this method is now guarantee to never return null, we can use that to simplify the next method. I have also rewritten it to use a for-each loop since we don't really need the `index` of each element.

```
Future<void> jsonToDatabaseSyncItem() async {
  final jsonObjectList = await getRemoteDatabase();

  for (final jsonObject in jsonObjectList) {
    print(jsonObject['DatabaseSyncItem']);
  }
}
```

I have also removed this line since it does nothing at all. If `remoteDatabaseList` is a `Future` you should just `await` on that instead of creating a new `Future`.

```
final jsonObjectList = await Future.value(remoteDatabaseList);
```

Also, the return type of `jsonToDatabaseSyncItem()` have been changed to `Future<void>` since we are never returning any value.

I am a little confused about your `main` but I think this is where it is most clear that you got a confused about `Future` and null-safety. I have tried to rewrite it so it is much cleaner but should still do the same:

```
Future<void> main(List<String> arguments) async {
  final list = await getRemoteDatabase();
  print(list.length);
  
  final dynamic jsonObject = list[0]['DatabaseSyncItem'];
  print(jsonObject);

  final toObject = DatabaseSyncItem.fromJson(jsonObject);
  print(toObject);
}
```

Comment: Fantastic answer :) this is what a good SO answer should look like IMO. I'm a programming noob and I sincerely appreciate the didactic attitude. Ill be giving the docs a read over the next few days. Thanks for the help julemand. Also, you were spot on about my confusion. I did learn a bit about null safety with Swift but using it with Futures also threw me a curve. So good to know.